# Differential equation and distribution theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Since distributions can not be multiplied ,then does the following equation (ODE)

$$ xy'(x)= \delta (x) $$

has a solution? Here $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: Distributions _can_ be multiplied by (the smooth function) $x$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions to this ODE are
$$
y(x) = -\delta(x) + aH(x) + b,
$$
where $a,b$ are constants and $H$ is the Heaviside step function.